# 2 кнопки "+" и "-", которые будут увеличивать/уменьшать наполнение на 5%

Tags: javascript, анимация

К элементу https://codepen.io/ipekt/pen/qdYbYE?q=termometr&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false нужно добавить 2 кнопки "+" и "-", которые будут увеличивать/уменьшать его наполнение на 5%. Как это реализовать?
    `<div id="termometre">
      <div id="termometreBase"></div>
    </div>`

Comment: какие попытки в JS предпринимались? мы не против с ними ознакомиться...

Comment: Была попытка изменить через js свойство height на +-5% у псевдоэлемента termometre::after. Но насколько я понял, на чистом js это невозможно, можно только достать это свойство. Вторая мысль - это скрыть текущий элемент заполнения температуры (termometre) и добавить отдельный класс, который бы при событии click добавлял/ удалял height +-5%. Что скажете?

Answer (score -2):

Делаешь 2 кнопки допустим тегом `div` пишешь в них + и -, вешаешь обработчик на `click`, и уже js'ом изменяешь высоту и псевдо-элемента :after у блока с id termometreBase меняешь высоту.

Comment: Есть более рациональное решение, чем изложенное мной?